# Responsive menu (iphone 4 to iphone 5)

Tags: css, iphone

I have edited our mobile menu (responsive menu) but the full word for example "Arbete som personlig assistent" is not showing at the menu at iphone 5 (http://vhassistans.se) http://prntscr.com/ejdsij - I have been trying to edit the size of text, but without any result.

```
 `font-size: 8 px;`
```

but it still doesn't work. Someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this selector :

```
#navPanel .link {
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(87, 93, 89, 0.15);
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px; /* I've modified this line */ 
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In style `style-mobile.css` line **601**

Comment: In what line? I am in style-mobile.css and i can just find navPanel .link here:

http://prntscr.com/ejdxaz

Comment: yes, in that selector, add the font-size property, for example : `font-size: 12px;`

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to validate this answer if it helps ;)